# How get fans gender of facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How get fans gender (percentages) of facebook page?
Using the graph api of facebook.
It's possible?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `/{page-id}/insights/{metric-name}` endpoint.

There are several kinds of metrics, including page fans, page likes, etc.

See the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/insights) for more info.

Comment: I don't know what happen. 
For example a use:

https://graph.facebook.com/lanacioncr/insights/page_fans?access_token=XXX

But I can't access these data.